# How would you show two matrices are not unitary similar

Tags: matrices

How would I show the following two matrices are not unitary similar.

$A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\quad$ and $\quad B =
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 4 \\
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Try computing the Frobenius norm (which is unitarily invariant) of both matrices.

Comment: I think if they frobenius norm is not equal they are not unitarly equivalent I think that is a theorem in the books I am using.

Comment: Exactly. Same, e.g., with the spectral norm.